# Ler um inteiro maior que 0 e devolver a soma entre os números que o compõe em Python

Tags: python, string

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como fazer um código, em Python, que leia um número inteiro maior que 0 digitado pelo usuário e some os números que compõem ele?

Ex:

Usuário digita 129

Programa retorna 12

Comment: Transforme a entra em uma string e então itere sobre essa string convertendo cada caractere para inteiro e os somando em um acumulador.

Answer (score 0):

Com o seguinte código você efetua a soma dos digitos do número:

```
n=int(input("Digita um número:"))

tot=0

while(n>0):
    dig=n%10
    tot=tot+dig
    n=n//10

print("A soma é:",tot)
```

Comment: Evite dar respostas por completo a esse tipo de pergunta. É um execício acadêmico o usuário não chegou a publicar nenhum tentativa de resolução. Uma resposta completa mais atrapalha do que ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que não é a resposta mais legível, e eu não recomendo usar isso em produção, mas a título de curiosidade vou deixar um *one-liner* que faz o que foi solicitado pelo OP.

```
print('Soma dos dígitos:', sum(map(int, input('Informe um número inteiro: '))))
```

Por mais que não seja legível, esse tipo de código mostra o quão flexível é a linguagem Python.